# Android what does the clipToPadding Attribute do?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to know what the `clipToPadding` attribute does for `ViewGroup` in Android ?

I've been through the docs and some websites but none I have come across actually explain what it does and what it means, well none that I could actually understand so I thought it might be a good idea to ask it here.

Answer (score 601, accepted):

You can use clipToPadding for views that scroll. Say you have a listview for example and you having padding set on the top and bottom. Normally the padding is visible no matter which items are visible on the screen. The diagram below represents a list with 10 items but only 4 are visible on screen, with default clipToPadding settings:

- (padding)
- item 4
- item 5
- item 6
- item 7
- (padding)

Now if you were to set `clipToPadding="false"` instead of just being applied normally to the entire view it only applies the padding to the end items, this is what you'd see in the same scenario:

- item 4
- item 5
- item 6
- item 7

Now if you were to scroll to the top or bottom of the list, this is what you would see:

- (padding)
- item 1
- item 2
- item 3
- item 4

OR

- item 7
- item 8
- item 9
- item 10
- (padding)

A practical usage for this is if you have a Floating Action Button for example, you should use clipToPadding combined with bottom padding to ensure the entirety of the bottom item can be seen without being obstructed by the FAB.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I am ready to pay if official docs start giving out this kind of explanation for other topics

Comment: Does it only apply to recyclerview or any viewgroup?

Comment: I love this comment and always that i face a clip to padding have to come back to it! Thanks :)

Comment: In this answer, would it be more clear to show that, for the second example, that item 3 and item 8 are partly visible because the padding is not taking space?

Answer (score 464):

I know that the top rated answer explains this pretty clearly through text but as its said,

"*A picture is worth thousand words*"

Here is a GIF worth 1500 depicting the same:

### (Left: `clipToPadding = "true"` Right: `clipToPadding = "false"` )

[image]

Comment: Yet somehow the text-based answers is easier to understand ;) Thanks for the vis though!

Comment: picture say much more than words, but words were much more complete... here not shown the end of the right list that what happened for it if it has bottom padding ...

Comment: @MHSFisher , the answered is meant to demonstrate the top padding

Answer (score 12):

A nice usage of `clipToPadding` is described in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O47H4PxMf9U (part of [Udacity's Material Design](https://de.udacity.com/course/material-design-for-android-developers--ud862) course)

Using `clipToPadding="false"` makes the scroll view scroll over the top Google Maps icon. This is due to both being inside the same `FrameLayout`.

[image: google play store of google maps, showing cliptopadding]

Answer (score 8):

I recommend you to take a look at this article https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.5x2hz7q0g

> Or maybe you want your RecyclerView to scroll underneath a transparent navigation bar — by using android:fitsSystemWindows=”true” in conjunction with android:clipToPadding=”false”, **your scrolling content will be behind the controls but, when scrolled to the bottom, the last item will still be padded to be above the navigation bar** (rather than hidden underneath!).

Answer (score -4):

Defines whether the `ViewGroup` will clip its children and resize (but not clip) any `EdgeEffect` to its padding, if padding is not zero. This property is set to `true` by default.

May be a boolean value, such as "true" or "false".

Related methods:

`setClipToPadding(boolean)`