# Android ScrollView with RecyclerView is shorter than I expected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-scrollview

I have two `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView`. The second `RecyclerView` named "`recyclerView`_main_article" can't be shown completely. I mean its bottom was cut out. I tried to add extra View named "empty" under the `RecyclerView` to make some space. After I added "empty", "`recyclerView`_main_article" was shown completely but "empty" was shorter than its height. 
Here is XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_title_line"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_top_movie_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="@string/top_movie_title"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_title_line"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view_title_line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_see_all_movies"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/see_all"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_title_line"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_main_video"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_title_line" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_title_line2"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView_main_video" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_top_article_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="@string/top_article_title"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_title_line2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view_title_line2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_see_all_articles"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/see_all"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_title_line2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_main_article"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_title_line2" />

        <!--<View
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView_main_article" />-->
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I apply HORIZONTAL to the RecyclerViews by this Kotlin code.

```
recyclerView_main_video.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, OrientationHelper.HORIZONTAL, false)
recyclerView_main_article.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, OrientationHelper.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

I use Android Studio 3.0.1 and my recyclerview version is 26.1.0.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
```

What should I do?? I need your help.

Comment: add **padding bottom** to second recyclerview and `android:clipToPadding =  false`

Comment: use **`android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`** insetad of **`ScrollView`**

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Thank you @NileshRathod for telling me NestedScrollView. It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Change `ScrollView` to `NestedScrollView`
>
> Add  `android:paddingBottom="50dp"`  `android:clipToPadding="false"` in second `recyclerview`

For [`clipToPadding`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40955714/8089770)

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_title_line"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_top_movie_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="@string/top_movie_title"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_title_line"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view_title_line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_see_all_movies"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/see_all"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_title_line"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_main_video"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_title_line" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_title_line2"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView_main_video" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_top_article_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="@string/top_article_title"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_title_line2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view_title_line2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_see_all_articles"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/see_all"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_title_line2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_main_article"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_title_line2" />

        <!--<View
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView_main_article" />-->
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you @VishvaDave. It works completely! I didn't know about NestedScrollView and the property "clipToPadding". This is my first Android app so I need to study harder! Thank you!!

Comment: @FESHIMO Happy to help :) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `RecyclerView` inside a `ScrollView` is a bad idea, the best practice is using a `recyclerview` and put everything you want to scroll inside it. If there is some views above your recycled items just make an header with is own `viewHolder` and put it in the first position of your `recyclerView`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have two horizontal RecyclerViews and the total height of all views is higher than device height. That's why I wrapped them with ScrollView. NestedScrollView solved my problem. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [`NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) instead of `ScrollView`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know NestedScrollView. The other user told me the detail so I chose it as the best answer, but thank you anyway.