# Allow Recyclerview Items to scroll past top of Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` list, in which I want the currently selected item to be shown at the **top** of the `RecyclerView`. I still however, want the entire list to be scrollable, therefore, removing views from above the selected item is not a possible solution.

It seems I need a mechanism where the `RecyclerView` items are able to scroll beyond the bounds of the `RecyclerView`. I'm not sure if this is possible, so if it is not, does anyone have a solution to ensuring the currently selected item scrolls to the top of the `RecyclerView`.

I have tried `smoothScrollToPosition()` but this doesn't work in the case of being at the bottom of the `RecyclerView`, and wanting one of the middle items to scroll to the top.

Many thanks

to Illustrate, I have a list of 4 items, the recyclerview cannot scroll as there is not enough items in the list.

[image]

Then I select an item

[image]

I then want the selected item to scroll to top, but for the item above to still be scrollable.

[image]

So, when I scroll up...

[image]

Comment: everything is possible my frnd..just remove the selected item from the list and add it at the first position of the list and then `notifyItemRangeInserted(0, selected_position);` recyclerView will auto scroll to top... :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I still want the items above the selected item to be scrollable to, I don't think this fixes that.

Comment: you want autoscroll or you want **the user to scroll** and you want keep the selected to its original position or do you want it  at the top?

Comment: got it my frnd :) working on it

Comment: you can delete all items till the selected position from the list and `notifyDataSetChanged()` and when the user tries to scroll up add those elements and again `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the `RecyclerView` set a bottom padding that is equal to three times your item's height then set `android:clipToPadding="false"`. This will let your bottom item scroll to the top and show the padding on the bottom item but only on the bottom item.

Here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40955714/6287910) to a similar question that lays this technique out rather well.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

lets assume that you have item on click listener for your recycler view, when user clicks on any item you get item position and view, below code is working for me

```
RecycleClick.addTo(firstRecyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new RecycleClick.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                    // YOUR CODE
                    int offset = position - yourRecyclerViewLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (yourRecyclerViewLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() > 0) offset -= 1;
                    yourRecyclerViewLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset);

                }
            });
```

make sure your layout manager comes from support library like this

```
android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
```

otherwise you will not find findFirstVisibleItemPosition() method etc