# How do I clip recyclerView after first item decoration at the top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a pinned `ItemDecoration` (a header section) added before first (top) child of the `RecyclerView`.

When I scroll the `RecyclerView`, first item goes behind the header section. Since the section is transparent it looks like that section and first item get overlapped.

How can I clip the `RecyclerView` so that the overlapping does not happen?

[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what you mean? It's difficult to imagine what you mean

Comment: I have added a .gif file in the question above.

Comment: please post your layout file too. I have a solution in mind, just want to be sure that what i think is correct

Comment: @Kushan - Layout file does not have any special code. It is just a recyclerView with TextView items. The header texts shown above in red color (e.g. A, B, C etc.) are added using ItemDecorations. Thank you.

Comment: Yea but since A is static i was wondering if its a separate view and not a part of the recyclerview

Comment: A is not static, it is added dynamically as itemDecoration when the initial letter of the item view changes. Hence A is added before all the items which start with A, and then B, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your `ItemDecoration` is using [`DrawOver()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html#onDrawOver(android.graphics.Canvas,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State)) for the sticky header. Try setting a top padding to the `RecyclerView` that has a height equal to the height of your header `android:paddingTop="somedp"` and set `android:clipToPadding="true"`. See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40955714/6287910) for a good description of clip to padding.

You may have to adjust how your item decoration is drawn but this should prevent your items from sliding under the header.