# Adjust button below the activity contents

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm having difficulty adjusting the layout of my activity, what I want is to have the contents inside a "scrollview", and at the bottom of the page have a button. My layout is already doing almost this, the problem that is happening is that when the content arrives to a certain point, it gets behind the button, which I want and keep the content always above the button regardless of the size.

my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fundo_degrade"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="br.com.cifrasemusica.cifrasmusica_teoriamusical.activity.ExercicioActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/Toolbar_Exercicio"
            layout="@layout/toolbar">
        </include>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/RecyclerView_Exercicio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/Button_enviarExercicio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="CONFIRMAR"
            android:background="@drawable/fundo_botao"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Why `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView` **FYI**  `RecyclerView` has its own scrolling behavior

Comment: You can try nesting `ScrollView` (or better `RecyclerView` directly) and Button within a `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView) then can use [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView) instead of Scrollview

But if there is only one recyclerview inside that then I suggest to not use `Scrollview`. as `Scrollview` is not for this purpose

> I want and keep the content always above the button regardless of the
>   size

For this you can try below solution :

```
android:paddingBottom="50dp" 
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

in `recyclerview`

For [cliptopedding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40955714/8089770)

Comment: ma'am no need to use `NestedScrollView` because there no other child view inside `ScrollView` and also `RecyclerView has its own scrolling behavior`

Comment: as you see in question there is one child in `ScrollView` and its `recyclerview` so i think ScrollView`  is meaningless

Comment: @DouglasNickson Happy to help :) let me know if any queries

Answer (score 1):

Remove `RecyclerView` from `ScrollView`  no need to use `ScrollView`

**FYI**

`RecyclerView` has its own scrolling behavior and your `ScrollView` has inly one child is `RecyclerView` so i think its meaningless to use `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView`

> it gets behind the button, which I want and keep the content always above the button regardless of the size.

Also and try to add some `bottom-padding`  or `bottom-margin` to your `RecyclerView` to show your bottom content at the end of screen

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fundo_degrade"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="br.com.cifrasemusica.cifrasmusica_teoriamusical.activity.ExercicioActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/Toolbar_Exercicio"
            layout="@layout/toolbar">
        </include>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/RecyclerView_Exercicio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="80dp" 
            android:clipToPadding="false" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



        <Button
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/Button_enviarExercicio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="CONFIRMAR"
            android:background="@drawable/fundo_botao"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

-Do one thing replace coordinator layout with linear layout with orientation vertical and remove scroll view because recycleview has it default scrolling property so and put weight 1 to recycle view using this below code you are able to achieve what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/fundo_degrade"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/Toolbar_Exercicio"
        layout="@layout/toolbar">
    </include>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView_Exercicio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/Button_enviarExercicio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="CONFIRMAR"
        android:background="@drawable/fundo_botao"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" /> 
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes below in the layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fundo_degrade"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="br.com.cifrasemusica.cifrasmusica_teoriamusical.activity.ExercicioActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/Toolbar_Exercicio"
            layout="@layout/toolbar">
        </include>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/RecyclerView_Exercicio"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/Button_enviarExercicio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="CONFIRMAR"
            android:background="@drawable/fundo_botao"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove `Scrollview` because recycle have its own scrolling property, now for more easy i change it to relative layout, set the `recycelerView` above the button so that button will never behind if `recycelerView` have more contain it will always be below of `recycelerView`, have look.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fundo_degrade"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/Toolbar_Exercicio"
            layout="@layout/toolbar">
        </include>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/RecyclerView_Exercicio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="id/btn">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>  

        <Button android:id="+id/btn"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/Button_enviarExercicio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="CONFIRMAR"
            android:background="@drawable/fundo_botao"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout >
```

Hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

You dont requre scrollview as you have `recycelerView` and button in `LinearLayout` and add `android:orientation="vertical"` in `LinearLayout` as shown below also

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fundo_degrade"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="br.com.cifrasemusica.cifrasmusica_teoriamusical.activity.ExercicioActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/Toolbar_Exercicio"
                layout="@layout/toolbar">
            </include>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/RecyclerView_Exercicio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


            <Button
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/Button_enviarExercicio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CONFIRMAR"
                android:background="@drawable/fundo_botao"
                 />
    </LinearLayout/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```