# Shared Content overlapping Bottom Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

My MainActivity's got a RecyclerView and a BottomNavigationView. Items in the RecyclerView are CardViews.

When I click an item that's halfway obscured by the BottomNavigationView (- will call it *BNV*), it "pops" over the BNV, then slides up to become the header in LaunchedActivity.

When backing out of LaunchedActivity, it slides down, over the BNV, then "snaps" back into place:

[image]

How can I either:

1. Have the shared content appear to slide from underneath the BNV, 
   or failing that,
2. Have the shared content start off invisible, and fade as it slides to the header

I've tried playing with the elevation of the BNV, I've tried setting sharedElementEnterTransition to Fade(), I've tried specifying excludeTarget with BottomNavigation; I can't seem to make things work how I'd like.

Here's the layout for MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            />
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activity_launched is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".LaunchedActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_launched"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And content_launched:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_launched"
        tools:context=".LaunchedActivity">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/launched_header"
            android:transitionName="header" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                  android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                  android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">
        <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/launched_title"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/launched_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Items in the RecyclerView call MainActivity.onItemClicked:

```
   fun onItemClicked(view: View, item: Item) {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, LaunchedActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("ITEM", item)
        val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            this,
            android.util.Pair<View, String>(view, "header")
        )
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
    }
```

This is the array that's in the recycler:

```
data class Item(val title: String, val text: String): Serializable

val itemList = listOf(Item("One", "1"), Item("Two", "2"),
        Item("Three", "3"), Item("Four", "4"), Item("Five", "5"))
```

Lastly, this is from LaunchedActivity.onCreate:

```
   with(window) {
        requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS)
        requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS)
        sharedElementEnterTransition = AutoTransition()
        sharedElementExitTransition = AutoTransition()
    }
```

LaunchedActivity.onCreate pulls the item out of the intent and sets launched_title and launched_text.

Comment: Can you share your Layout and onClick code

Comment: Give margin between recyclerview and bottom navigation. Also share your layout and activity code.

Comment: I've added layout and code

Comment: i'm sure the reason is in ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation because if I'm not mistaken it is rendering as overlay...so it will always on top of all content

Answer (score 3):

Add in recyclerView's item's CardView

```
app:cardMaxElevation="8dp"
```

and give your BNV

```
app:elevation="16dp"
```

give it a try, try with more difference in elevation as clicked cardview has more elevation than actual elevation

Comment: I'm still getting the same effect: the card pops above the BNV before, and snaps back after.

Comment: @brismith try writing bottomNavigationView?.bringtoFront()  at this - fun onItemClicked(view: View, item: Item).

Comment: bnv.bringToFront does not affect the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of `clipToPadding` it can add padding to the bottom views so it does not obstruct the bottom views.

So try setting `clipToPadding = "true"` and check if it solves.

[Android what does the clipToPadding Attribute do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953049/android-what-does-the-cliptopadding-attribute-do)

Also your layout activity file has `<RecyclerView>` set to 0dp.

Use a `<RelativeLayout>` outside and set `layout_above="@bnv"` in  `<RecyclerView>` somewhat similar to this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation1"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <com.nxtoff.plzcome.commonutills.BottomNavigationViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewpager"
                android:background="#999999" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </FrameLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_colors"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/xfb_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="22dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@color/colorloader"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_fab"
        android:tint="@color/colorviolet"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorloader"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
         />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT 1:**

Try out this code and let me know.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        />
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've added clipPadding and clipChildren attributes, to no effect. Also I switched the ConstraintLayout (that's why rv's height and width were 0) to RelativeLayout, and specified rv's layout_above to bnv. I still get the same behavior.  FWIW, I've seen other Android apps with the same effect: two of which are Zinio, and PlayerFM. I wish I weren't stuck with it.

Comment: I am sure there's a solution to this.. I still think that rv's not accepting `layout_above`.. Let me try it out and get back to you.