# Android: RecyclerView padding preventing full screen experience

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'd like to add some padding to my recycler view so the status bar doesn't cover the first item. The problem is when I apply top padding, a solid white shows on top preventing the full screen experience.

[image]

Here is my layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecentVizzyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="48dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/lightGreen"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and I'm setting no limits flag to my screen:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `android:clipToPadding="false"` on your RecyclerView.

That will allow the paddingTop (and bottom, if you want), to be part of the scrollable part.

A better description is found here:
[Android what does the clipToPadding Attribute do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953049/android-what-does-the-cliptopadding-attribute-do)

Comment: I'd be surprised if that works, because clipToPadding have to be set on RecyclerView parent, not the RecyclerView itself.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it :) I just added this to the above recyclerview and the list can scroll behind the notch now without the white thing.

Comment: @ror No, it has to go on the RecyclerView itself. The RV has the padding, and is a ViewGroup. clipToPadding tells the ViewGroups children that they can use the padding space to scroll. In this case, the children are the list elements in the RV.