# curved collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Im trying to make a curved a collapsing toolbar but without having a white corners covering my content, I have successfully created the view but even setting the AppBarLayout background to transparent didnt give me transparent edges

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_curved_top"
            app:elevation="0dp">


            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">



                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_home_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">


                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to fix this issue by giving a `marginTop ="-16dp"` to my nested scrolling view and giving the `AppBarLayout` an elevation so it always covers the nested scrollview.

Dont forget to add the same value you subtracted in the marginTop in the first view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting `android:clipToPadding="false"` for the AppBarLayout. At this point I'm just guessing the issue and fix. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953049/android-what-does-the-cliptopadding-attribute-do) a very nice explanation on what clipToPadding does

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:outlineProvider="background"`.
Your view must be clipped as background it owns.
And then try `android:clipToPadding="false"`.